# php syntax $a = $b = 1;

Tags: php, syntax

Is

```
$a = 1;
$b = $a;
```

equal to writing this?

```
$a = $b = 1;
```

Will the second example always put 1 as value to both $a and $b, even if $a and $b already has a value assigned to them?

Comment: Yes it will <filler />

Comment: Multiple assignments (with additional operators) shouldn't be in maintainable code.

Comment: @Mike B, please elaborate as I don't see the problem when we're talking about initialization statements as in example.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I added the additional-operator qualifier so this question doesn't devolve into interesting, but useless, php trivia/hackery due to order of operations. *Why does this code return what it does???* `$x++-2/$b+=-$x++(^2*2)+=5`

Comment: @MikeB - That code returns a deep-seated desire to punch anyone who would write it in production. :P

Comment: @Mike B, so to be clear, nothing is wrong with strict, *multiple assignment*.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary `$dude = $wheres = $my = $car = 0;` Is fine. `$dude = $wheres = $my = $car + 1 = 0;` Not fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, PHP will put `1` in `$b` then put `$b` value in `$a`, i.e. `1`.

There is no ambiguity as the first assignment is `$b = 1`, the next is `$a = $b`.

Answer (score 5):

[Quoting the documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is,
>   the value of "$a = 3" is 3. This allows you to do some tricky things:

```
<?php

$a = ($b = 4) + 5; // $a is equal to 9 now, and $b has been set to 4.

?>
```

So, to answer your question, the result of the assignment `$b = 1` is 1, and therefore, `$a = $b = 1` would assign the value of `$b = 1`--which is to say 1--to `$a`.

**That being said**, abusing this can lead to code that is hard to read.